# java relative file path issue in dependant projects

Tags: java, maven, file, classpath, filepath

I've a maven project called Project_1. In this project I've a file reader which reads a config file(using relative path) from resources folder(which is sourced) of this project. I've another maven project called Project_2 in which Project_1 is added as dependency. When I'm running the Project_2 now, the relative path for reading config file is not working as ClassPath is set based on Project_2. Could anyone please help me to use proper file path which works in any condition.

NOTE: I don't want to use absolute file path, as I want these projects to be portable. Project_2 alone is customer facing and config file is specific to Project_1 which is not allowed to be configured by customer facing application.

Comment: If anyone doesn't know the answer, please do not down vote. If you understand the question and know the answer well, please help me. I'll grateful. But please don't discourage.

Comment: You need to offer more details. pom.xml of both projects would help. People downvoted you, I assume, because you're asking for help without respecting the general guidelines.

Comment: So, does your config file from project A ends up in project A's artifact?

Comment: My advice: don't try to solve this with the filesystem, but with the classpath. That's the only thing Project_1 can control when used by other projects.